# calculate NULL values in mathematical string without replacing them with 0 PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, math, plsql, operators

I need to calculate the result of a mathematical expression stored in a string (For example: `'A*(B+C)+(D*E)+F+G*(H+I)'`).
The string can contain any mathematical operator.

The first step of my program (a PL/SQL procedure) is to replace the variables with their values (which can be `NULL`)

But I can't replace the `NULL` values with zeros because I need to distinguish if the total result is NULL or `0`.

example #1:

I expect to have NULL as a result and not 0.

```
NULL*(B+C)+(NULL*10)+NULL+5*(NULL+NULL)
```

example #3:

I expect to have 0 as a result

```
NULL*(B+C)+(NULL*10)+0+5*(NULL+NULL)
```

example 2:

I expect to have 99 as a result

```
NULL*(B+C)+(NULL*10)+99+5*(NULL+NULL)
```

Is there any way to do this dynamically? the mathematical expression can be of any other type (`'A*B+C*D+E*G'` or `'A*(B+C)+D*(E+F)'` or simple `A*B` or `A+B+C`).

If there are no brackets, the mathematical operators' priorities must be respected as in standard calculation.

After replacing all values and cleaning the expression from NULL values,  I use execute immediate to calculate the final result.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your requirement does not make sense. NULL+NULL results in NULL, but 0+NULL results in 0, yet 10*NULL results in NULL? Plese update your question with the full definition of NULL vs. non-NULL values handling for all possible operators.

Comment: If there is a NULL value inside for my opinion nearly every time the result must be NULL, except all your NULLs are inside the brackets in something like (...)*0 -> 0 or (...)^0 -> 1. F.e. in your example #3: IF the first NULL stands for, I don't know, but can be 5 Millions, then the result is 0 + 5 000 000 *(A+B) (...+ 10 times of anything and 5 times of anything else) --> implicit you replace all NULLs by 0

Comment: maybe you could do the following: Replace all NULL twice with random values and compare the results. If both results are same you can hope, the NULLs doesn't Play any role, but of course you can find one of the  combinations, that gives you false friends.

Comment: You should note that `NULL` means **not defined** rather than **0** for mathematical expression. `not defined * 5 => still not defined`. But you could replace each term by `NVL(..., 0)`, e.g. `NVL(A,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using dynamic SQL (using Oracle's logic for `NULL` values in calculations - so `NULL + anything = NULL` and `NULL * anything = NULL`):

```
DECLARE
  SUBTYPE VARIABLE_TYPE IS VARCHAR2(5);
  TYPE VARIABLE_MAP IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARIABLE_TYPE;

  variables  VARIABLE_MAP;
  expression VARCHAR2(4000) := 'A*(B+C)+(D*E)+F+G*(H+I)';
  v          VARIABLE_TYPE;
  e          VARCHAR2(4000);
  r          NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- Populate the variables values
  variables('A') := 1;
  variables('B') := 2;
  variables('C') := 3;
  variables('D') := 4;
  variables('E') := 5;
  variables('F') := 6;
  variables('G') := 7;
  variables('H') := 8;
  variables('I') := 9;

  -- Replace the variables with their values:
  e := expression;
  v := variables.FIRST;
  WHILE v IS NOT NULL LOOP
    e := REPLACE( e, v, COALESCE( TO_CHAR( variables(v) ), 'NULL' ) );
    v := variables.NEXT(v);
  END LOOP;

  -- Perform the calculation
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :1 := ' || e || '; END;' USING IN OUT r;

  -- Output the result
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r );
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
150
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested code but I tried to run your code with these values : 

  variables('A') := NULL;
  variables('B') := 2;
  variables('C') := 3;
  variables('D') := NULL;
  variables('E') := NULL;
  variables('F') := NULL;
  variables('G') := NULL;
  variables('H') := 8;
  variables('I') := 9; 
and it failed because e returned *(2+3)+(*)++*(8+9) before the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  The expected result is NULL.

Comment: @user8159167 Updated

Comment: I really need to avoid the standard NULL definition, as I have said in my post the mathematical expressions are dynamic soit's possible to have something like :   'A*(B+C)+(D*E)+F+G*(H+I)+2 

So I expect to have : 2 as result.  With the COALESCE I still get the wrong result (I get NULL instead of 2, because the execute immediate cannot calculate the expression containing an unknown value). But what is required here is to ignore NULL values if NULL+ or +NULL and to ignore the whole A*B if any of the operands is NULL. I hope it's clear ?

Comment: @user8159167 Good luck with that - you can write your own [tokenizer/parser in Java](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/) and then use `loadjava` to run it in the database and implement your custom logic.

Answer (score -1):

There is a nice function here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/434baca4-56dd-4ba3-896c-a04e2d29b5ef/stack-with-sql-server?forum=transactsql

but this is for SQL Server. You will have to adapt it for handling operators such as -*,/, (& ). & you can manage your nulls here.

Basically you have to push this expression in a stack & evaluate (Pop) & solve your expression.

```
create table dbo.Stack
(
stkID int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
stkData varchar(50) not null,
)
go

create procedure dbo.spStackPush
(
@stkData varchar(10)
)
as
begin
set nocount on
insert into Stack (stkData) values (@stkData)
if @@error <> 0 raiserror('Could not push to stack', 16, 1)
return 0
end
go

create procedure dbo.spStackPop
(
@stkData varchar(10) output
)
as
begin
set nocount on
declare @stkID int
select
@stkData = stkData,
@stkID = stkID
from dbo.Stack
where stkID = (select max(stkID) from dbo.Stack)

delete from dbo.Stack where stkID = @stkID
return 0
end
go

create procedure dbo.spStackEvaluate
(
@stkData varchar(10) output
)
as
begin
set nocount on
declare @stkLeft varchar(10)
declare @stkRight varchar(10)
declare @stkNext varchar(10)

exec dbo.spStackPop @stkData output

if @stkData = '+'
begin
exec dbo.spStackPop @stkLeft output
exec dbo.spStackPop @stkRight output

set @stkData = cast(@stkLeft as int) + cast(@stkRight as int)
end

if exists(select 1 from dbo.Stack)
begin
exec dbo.spStackPop @stkNext output
exec dbo.spStackPush @stkData
exec dbo.spStackPush @stkNext
exec dbo.spStackEvaluate @stkData output
end

return 0
end
go

-- Test script
delete dbo.Stack

declare @stkData varchar(10)

exec dbo.spStackPush '10'
exec dbo.spStackPush '+'
exec dbo.spStackPush '20'
exec dbo.spStackPush '+'
exec dbo.spStackPush '30'
exec dbo.spStackPush '40'
exec dbo.spStackPush '+'

exec dbo.spStackEvaluate @stkData output
print @stkData
```

Comment: `sql` tag is not synonymous with Microsoft SQL SERVER.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov yes i know. I wanted to show the approach to be used of using stack as datastructure to evaluate expressions. I added the code (event though of sql server) so that if link breaks the code remains.